# How to find the zeros of $\{X^2+Y^2-1, X^3+Y^3+XY-1\}$ over $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-curves

I am working on the following exercise:

> Find the zero set of $\{X^2+Y^2-1, X^3+Y^3+XY-1\}$ over the affine plane $\mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{C}) := \mathbb{C}^2$.

I admit that I do not come very far with this. I tried to plug in the identity $1 = X^2+Y^2$ into $X^3+Y^3+XY = 1$ but it lead to nowhere.  Could you please give me a hint?

For context: We have just recently learned about the very basics of algebraic curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A technique for solving this type of symmetric equations is passing to the new set of variable:
$$x+y=S, xy=P.$$
$$x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy=S^2-2P$$
$$x^3+y^3+xy=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)+xy=(x+y)((x+y)^2-3xy)+xy=S(S^2-3P)+P$$
And the system becomes

$S^2-2P=1\rightarrow P=\frac{S^2-1}{2}$

$S^3-3SP+P=1$

$$S^3-3S\frac{S^2-1}{2}+\frac{S^2-1}{2}=1$$
$$2S^3-3S^3+3S+S^2-1=2$$
$$-S^3+S^2+3S-3=0$$
$$S^3-S^2-3S+3=0$$
$$S^2(S-1)-3(S-1)=0$$
$$(S-3)(S^2-1)=0\rightarrow$$
$$S_1=3, S_2=1, S_3=-1\rightarrow P_1=4, P_2=P_3=0$$
Now, write the quadratic equations
$$z^2-S_1z+P_1=0$$
$$z^2-3z+4=0, z_{1,2}=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{9-16}}{2}=\frac{3\pm i\sqrt{7}}{2}\rightarrow$$
$$x_1=\frac{3+i\sqrt{7}}{2}, y_1=\frac{3-i\sqrt{7}}{2}$$
$$x_2=\frac{3-i\sqrt{7}}{2}, y_2=\frac{3+i\sqrt{7}}{2}$$
$$z^2-S_2z+P_2=0$$
$$z^2-z=0\rightarrow z_1=0, z_2=1\rightarrow$$
$$x_3=1, y_3=0; x_4=0, y_4=1$$
And so on for $S_3, P3$.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply $x^2+y^2-1=0$ by $x+y$ and subtract from the second equation and you get,

$$(x+y)(1-xy)=1-xy$$ so either
$$xy=1$$ or $$x+y=1$$ from here it should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions are $(x,y)$ with $x=0$, or $x=1$ or $x=\left( \pm \sqrt{\sqrt{-3} + 1}\right)/\sqrt{2}$. So
$$
(x,y)=(1,0),(0,1),
$$
or $xy=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: put $a = x+y$ and $b=xy$.

We have $1 = x^2+y^2=a^2-2b$,
$x^3+y^3 = (x+y)(x^2+y^2-xy)  = (x+y)(1-xy) = a(1-b)$ and so on.